# Do I need to apply USPS Patch (SUPEE-7616)?

Tags: patches

> On January 17, 2016, USPS made several changes to their services,
>   rates, and package names. The updates are reflected in this release,
>   and include the following changes:
>
> Standard Post renamed “Retail Ground” Flat Rate Box for Priority Mail
>   Express Eliminated Because the USPS changes are not included in the
>   security patch, earlier versions of Magento must be updated by
>   installing the SUPEE-7616 patch. The patch is available for download
>   in the same location as the security patch bundle.

I haven't enabled USPS from my admin. I was wondering if I need to install this patch.

Reason I am asking this is because I haven't installed earlier version of patches of USPS. To install this patch I will have to install them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be wise to patch regardless if you use the service as the files in question could be used to leverage admin access.

> While there are no confirmed attacks related to the security issues,
>   certain vulnerabilities can potentially be exploited to access
>   customer information or take over administrator sessions.

- https://community.magento.com/t5/News-Announcements/Important-New-Security-Releases-and-Patches/td-p/26736

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the patch it looks to be removing the `Standard Post` option and adding `Retail Ground` there is no actual security improvements in the SUPEE-7616
e.g

```
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php
@@ -544,7 +544,7 @@ class Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Usps
                  '1'      => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Priority Mail'),
                  '2'      => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Priority Mail Express Hold For Pickup'),
                  '3'      => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Priority Mail Express'),
-                 '4'      => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Standard Post'),
+                 '4'      => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Retail Ground'),
                  '6'      => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Media Mail Parcel'),
                  '7'      => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Library Mail Parcel'),
                  '13'     => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Priority Mail Express Flat Rate Envelope'),
```

If you are using USPS shipping service then i would suggest to apply this patch.

Comment: Haven't noticed any issues yet, we don't use the affected services that have either been renamed or removed.